# Prevent Android Studio installation from using users local directories

Tags: android-studio, installation

As a teacher, I am installing Android Studio in for a computer lab. We have shared computers on which users log in.
The problem is that Android Studio insists on installing SDK and a lot of other things in users local directories (users/user_name/local/appdata and users/user_name/local/AppData).
Since the SDK is several hundreds MB heavy and we have roaming profile thisis not acceptable at all.

What I did:

- I set up several envrionment variables to non users local directories: ANDROID_SDK_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, GRADLE_USER_HOME, GRADLE_HOME.
- I edited the idea.properties file to change idea.config.path and idea.system.path to non local directories
- During Android Studio first run I explicitely choose the SDK location.

Still here I am with the SDK located in users/local/appData

I am running out of idea. I am installing version 3.4 by I had the exact same problem with 3.3.